# Transitive Gradle dependencies in Android library projects using Android Gradle Plugin 7.3.0+

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-publish

I have a library project A which has a dependency to another library project B in this way:

```kotlin
api(libs.libraryB) { artifact { type = "aar" } }
```

My app has a dependency to library A:

```kotlin
api(libs.libraryA) {
    isTransitive = true
}
```

So the dependencies look like this:

```
App <- Library A <- Library B
```

This all works fine when library A and library B both are on Android Gradle Plugin version 7.2.2 but fails when either of them are updated to 7.3.0:

```
   > Failed to transform library-b-1.0.0 (com.mycompany:library-b:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
```

I have looked into my Maven2 repository and the artifacts are there (this is library project B - that the build complains about is missing:

[image: Library project B]

Side-note: Library project A builds and deploys without issue if AGP is updated, it's the transitive dependency case that fails.

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE 2022-09-29** Root cause was not AGP 7.3.0. Rather, it was a "refactoring" that I made at the same time as updating... See accepted answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

This was a red herring.

Culprit: My failed attempt to rewrite a dependency declaration on library A using Gradle version catalogs.

I had attempted to change this statement (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
api("com.mycompany:library-b:1.0.0@aar") {
        isTransitive = true
}
```

into:

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
api(libs.libraryB) {
    artifact {
        type = "aar"
        isTransitive = true
    }
}
```

libs.versions.toml.gradle:

```yaml
libraryB = { module = "com.mycompany:library-b", version.ref = "1.0.0" }
```

This doesn't work either:

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
api(libs.libraryB) { isTransitive = true }
```

libs.versions.toml.gradle:

```yaml
libraryB = { module = "com.mycompany:library-b", version.ref = "1.0.0@aar" }
```